# How to make a person walk within a Unity scene?

Tags: unity, art, graphics-design

I have a person in my Unity scene. My person follows waypoints and move. However, the movement is very unrealistic, the person seems to be floating through the scene rather than walking. How to make a person walk in unity?

Comment: What about following [tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/intermediate/live-training-archive/character-animation-setup)?

Comment: Have you tried using Unity's `NavMesh` ?

Comment: @TomTsagk No I haven't

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy answer.
First you need to decide how do you want to handle your character walk.
For what you said you will handle it like a point&click game so you will of course need a navmesh (try to take also a look to the new navmesh component:
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NavMeshComponents
).
After that you will need to create an animator controller, your character will move based on your animations. Blend multiple animations to get a natural result (from idle to walk and from walk to run... by using the animator controller you will just need idle walk and run animations and the controller will blend them. just make sure your change of state of the animator controller is based of a float variable).

That's the basic idea.

You should try to understand how animator controller work first. Read doc and tutorial of animator controller if you want to start to solve your problem.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that [the character model needs to have a proper rig and you need to tell Unity which bone has which function](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfiguringtheAvatar.html).